# Switch LEDs in Series

Tags: led, series

I have an array of 20 10V LEDs @500 ma. I would like to connect them all in series, as my driver is capable of this, but control 4 sets of 5, having any set combination on or off. I could do this with relays, opening the relay so the set lights up, then closing it so it bypasses, but what would be the solid state equivalent?

Comment: The real question is, is your LED driver voltage output capable of 20 x 10V LEDs = 200V forward voltage worst case? Otherwise you won't be able to turn any of the LEDs in series on if you don't forward bias all of the LEDs enough.

Answer (score 1):

The solid state equivalent to a relay is a transistor. Maybe like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnmzBP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The trouble is this: what do you connect to the gates of the MOSFETs (M1-M5)? In order to turn them on (making them look like a closed relay), you have to apply a voltage at the gate that's greater than at the source. How do you do that?

You can generate a floating power supply for each transistor, then interface to it through an optocoupler or something like that.

Alternately, look for a "solid state relay". They come in many kinds: some are good only for AC, others DC. Obviously you'd want the DC variety. They are essentially MOSFETs, plus some level-shifting functionality which makes interfacing with the floating gate trivial.

Comment: Place a zener from gate to source on each FET - say 10V or whatever is enough to ensure full drive - depends on the FET. Place a resistor - say 100k, across each zener to set each gate-source voltage to zero volts in the default state. Then drive each FET gate via a resistor from V+ (plus a jellybean pnp bipolar transistor or other high side driver) .| FET M! must be able to turn on with Vgs <= Vf_D1, but the rest are fairly likely to work with most FETS.

Comment: I think Russell's solution will work. I might be tempted to use PMOS for the top FET, with zener from gate to source, and npn pulling gate down. Otherwise it may get into a steady state condition where the top LED is not fully off and the transistor is dissipating a lot of power.

Comment: There are [solid-state relais](http://www.ni.com/white-paper/4125/en/) formed by a pair LED+Phototransistor in the same package. Since the control signal is optical, they essentially solve that floating gate issue